# How to implement dropdown menu as per below requirements in angular2

Tags: html, angular

By default I want to set the value in the dropdown from this: `{{getTeamName(employee.team)}}` and bind the value from the `{{team.$value}}`.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="team">Designation</label>
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" [ngModelOptions]={standalone:true}">
        <option *ngFor="let team of teams">{{team.$value}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Function:

```
getTeamName(key) {
    let result = this.teams.filter(item => item.$key == key);
    if (result.length > 0) {
        return result[0].$value;
    }
    return '';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <select [(ngModel)]="employee.team" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
      <option *ngFor="let team of teams"  [value]="team.$key" [selected]="employee.team == team.$key" >{{team.$value}}</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers).

Comment: The problem is explained but the solution is not. Also, if this is the definitive solution to your problem, you should check it as the accepted one.

Comment: How does this solved your problem, please explain this things, just writing an answer doesn't mean that will be helpful for others?

Answer (score 0):

You could directly consider binding `emplyee.team` to pre-populate `team` object in `ngModel` & for populating `team` value inside dropdown use `[ngValue]="team"` on option level. Not sure what is `team.$value`, I assumed you want to display `team.name`.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="team">Designation</label>
   <select [(ngModel)]="employee.team" [ngModelOptions]={standalone:true}">
       <option [ngValue] *ngFor="let team of teams">{{team.name}}</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: in employee.tam only stored key of team and in teams stored key and value of team

Comment: @Krunal I don't get you, could you please elaborate more on it?

Comment: so I got the team name in employee.team using  getTeamName(employee.team)

Comment: So then? what is `team.$value`?

Comment: @Krunal you had something wrong in the approach that you followed